# item placement algorithm

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

So I'm in search of an algorithm for determining item placements, however, I'm having difficulty formalizing my measurement for the "goodness" of a location.

Here's the problem:  I have a set of `k` items that I want to place along a line.  Each item has a width, and no two items can overlap.  Each item also has a corresponding interval - all the intervals are fixed, non-overlapping, and form a partition of some segment of the line.

I'd like to place each item so that it is centered in its interval, but I'm not guaranteed that the intervals are wider than the items.

So, as a compromise I'm willing to shift items partially (or fully) out of their interval.  However, I'm not willing to change the order of the items (they have to stay in the order of their intervals).

Is there a good algorithm for finding the "best" placement of the items along the line according to my (loosely defined) measure?

Comment: Considering two items, (a=0-10) and (b=1-2), which should come first?

Comment: Just an observation about the problem: since the intervals are non-overlapping and you're willing to shift items out of their intervals, it seems the intervals don't really matter, only their centres do. You can ask the question with just an "ideal location" for each item, saying you want the order preserved, etc.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: you're right; I suspect the OP has more desired constraints than they've mentioned.  Either that, or this is homework designed to determine if they can grasp your precise point.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: +1 valid point.  I meant to mention that keeping the items in their intervals is preferable to not (so the goodness decreases more rapidly with distance once entirely out of the interval) but forgot to mention it.

Comment: You may try to use [KKT conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) to minimize the sum of the distances from the center of your objects to the center of its corresponding intervals. You could model the non overlapping condition with the inequalities (ie distance greater than the sum of radii)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here is a solution for perhaps the simplest way I could interpret your question:

Let us suppose that for each item, we consider two possibilities:

1. We place it at its intended location (ie the center of the interval)
2. We don't

Then, we can reformulate this problem as the following function:  Find the maximal subcollection of items which can be placed at the center of their interval without overlapping.

This seems like something that ought to have a greedy solution, but I must confess that the best I was able to do was to come up with a pretty naive dynamic programming algorithm.  Here is how I formulated the recurrence:

Suppose that we are considering the nth item (starting from the left), and that we want to assign it such that the left edge of this item does not pass the right most front of all preceding items.  Then, it must be true that the optimal assignment satisfies:

```
best_align(n, right) = 
     if center[n]-radius[n] > right[n]:
          max(best_align(n+1, right+radii[n], 1+best_align(n+1,center[n]+radius[n])
     else:
          best_align(n+1, right+radius[n])
```

This has an obvious DP solution, which I coded up (in python).  Here is the result:

```
#Assumes that the items are sorted left-to-right by their centers
def best_align(radii, centers):

    assignments = { (radii[0]+centers[0]):[0], (-100000):[] }

    for i in range(1, len(radii)):

        nc = centers[i] + radii[i]
        nassignments = { nc : [i] }

        for right, assigned in assignments.items():

            #Handle case where object is not inserted
            nr = right+radii[i]
            if not nr in nassignments or len(assigned) > len(nassignments[nr]):
                nassignments[nr] = assigned

            #Handle inclusion case
            if right <= centers[i]-radii[i] and len(assigned) >= len(nassignments[nc]):
                nassignments[nc] = assigned + [i]


        assignments = nassignments

    return max([ (len(l), l) for l in assignments.values() ])[1]
```

The variable radii are the radii of the various items, while centers are the target assignment positions.  The algorithm returns the largest subset of the items which can be placed at the desired positions.  The remaining items just have to be fudged as best as possible.  For example, here are some outputs:

> In [11]: plc.best_align( [ 1, 5, 1], [0, 2, 3] )
>
> Out[11]: [2]

Another example:

> In [18]: plc.best_align( [1, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12] )
>
> Out[18]: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

The time complexity of this implementation is cubic on account of the naive way the sets of assignments are handled.  One could easily optimize to get a quadratic solution by replacing the python lists with references back to the previous lists they were constructed from (though it would make the presentation nastier).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a loosely coupled constraint system.  Roughly, you can find the "best" placement (not guaranteed to be "best", but should be "functional") by doing a depth-first search into the associated constraints for constraining elements.

Let me describe.  For the first run, try to place all the elements centered on their interval.  Check to see for overlapping objects.  When you encounter an overlapping object, tentatively move that object away from the overlap; check that system for overlaps.  Repeat for all overlaps.

This will preserve the order of objects according to the order of the intervals.  It should be possible to "score" the value of each iteration by the amount of divergence from the intervals, to attempt to minimize the distance from the intervals, if such a thing is desired.

Comment: what about a case where items a, b, and c are adjacent, and all three overlap?  It's unclear to me what should happen to b without knowing what should happen to a and c, which depends on their other neighbors.